# What is the uniform in this photo of my Great Grandmother’s father?

Tags: identification, uniform, imperial-germany

My Great Great Grandfather - Assuming late 1800s. Possibly Germany?  Looking to identify the uniform or badge on the hat.

[image]

I have no other background information. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to History SE! It seems that you have not uploaded a photo.

Comment: There's no such thing as "no other background information" in case of a family photo. Give us what you know: Paternal or maternal side? Where and when were parent and grandparents on that side born? Siblings? Education? Etc.

Comment: Looks like you might start looking in Basel, Switzerland.

Comment: Any chance of a higher resolution photo?  Is there anything on the back?